# How do I scrape data from multiple webpages with BeauitfulSoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with the following code and I am sorry, I am new to this all, I want to add the strings in the FullPage list to the actual URL and then I want to visit them and scrape some data from the pages. So far, It has been good but I do not know how to make it visit the other links in the list.

The output will only give me the data of one page but I need the data for 30 pages, how can I make this program to go over each link?

The URL has a pattern, the first part has 'http://arduinopak.com/Prd.aspx?Cat_Name=' and then the second part has the product category name.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FullPage = ['New-Arrivals-2017-6', 'Big-Sales-click-here', 'Arduino-Development-boards',
            'Robotics-and-Copters']


urlp1 = "http://www.arduinopak.com/Prd.aspx?Cat_Name="
URL = urlp1 + FullPage[0]

for n in FullPage:
    URL = urlp1 + n
    page = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


descList = bsObj.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "panel-default"})
for desc in descList:
    print(desc.getText(separator=u' '))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FullPage = ['New-Arrivals-2017-6', 'Big-Sales-click-here', 'Arduino-Development-boards',
            'Robotics-and-Copters']

urlp1 = "http://www.arduinopak.com/Prd.aspx?Cat_Name="
URL = urlp1 + FullPage[0]

for n in FullPage:
    URL = urlp1 + n
    page = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    descList = bsObtTj.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "panel-default"})
    for desc in descList:
        print(desc.geext(separator=u' '))
```

If you want to scape each links then moving last 3 lines of your code into loop will do it.

Comment: Was that all? Oh my, I am such a beginner. Thanks so much bro!

Comment: I am glad that it was helpful. Just accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your current code fetches all the links but it stores only one `BeautifulSoup` object reference. You could instead store them all in the array or process them before visiting another URL (as shown below).

```
for n in FullPage:
    URL = urlp1 + n
    page = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    descList = bsObj.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "panel-default"})
    for desc in descList:
        print(desc.getText(separator=u' '))
```

Also, note that the names using PascalCase are by convention reserved for classes. `FullPage` would usually be written as `fullPage` or `FULL_PAGE` if it's meant to be constant.